# Radix Sort using SSE

Tags: c++, sorting, sse

I am trying to write the C++ implementation of radix sort using SSE.
Here is the current implementation of the radix sort without SSE (based on Wikipedia).

```cpp
int numBuckets = 16;
int radix = 4;
int mask = 0xF;
void radix_sort(long* arr, int N) {
    int nradix, oldCount, total;
    long val;

    int counts[numBuckets];
    long arrCopy[N];

    for (int nradix = 0; nradix < 64; nradix+=radix) {
        // refresh the counts
        for (int j = 0; j < numBuckets; ++j) counts[j] = 0;

        // get the counts and the copy
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            val = arr[j];
            ++counts[(val >> nradix) & mask];
            arrCopy[j] = val;
        }

        // get the starting index
        total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < numBuckets; ++j) {
            oldCount = counts[j];
            counts[j] = total;
            total += oldCount;
        }

        // copy back to the array
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            val = arrCopy[j];
            arr[counts[(val >> nradix) & mask]++] = val;
        }
    }
}
```

The only SSE-able thing that I can think is only when it refresh the counts, using `_mm_setzero_ps()`.
Is there any other place that SSE can be implemented to speed up the algorithm? Thank you.

Comment: Most sorting algorithms are difficult-to-impossible to vectorize. Sorting networks are one exception to this though, so you might want to take a look at those if you just want to try implementing a sort algorithm using SIMD - only good for small N, but might be useful as the inner part of a larger sorting implementation.

Comment: Also, I would just use memset for setting the counts to zero; your compiler will emit the fastest way to zero a buffer for your native architecture (if you use `-march=native`)

Comment: SSE is not especially good at making histograms and computing prefix sums, but you can improve the histogram code (one of the slower parts of this code) [a lot](http://fastcompression.blogspot.nl/2014/09/counting-bytes-fast-little-trick-from.html).

Comment: @PaulR I'm looking forward to see if anyone finds a creative way to do a quick sort using the AVX512 compress/expand instructions.